# Get all recoreds which is not available in another table

Tags: mysql

I have to tables `mdl1` and `mdl2`  both have the same attributes (columns).

I want to get all the `ps_stud_id` values which does not exist in `mdl2` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ps_stud_id 
from mdl1
where ps_stud_id not in
(
  select ps_stud_id 
  from mdl2
)
```

or

```
select mdl1.ps_stud_id 
from mdl1
left outer join mdl2 on mdl1.ps_stud_id = mdl2.ps_stud_id
where mdl2.ps_stud_id is null
```

Comment: the second query is definitely better. I would suggest that you remove the first option.

Comment: Some find the first query better to read and this is not a performance problem in general. Only if the list in the `in` clause is really big.

Comment: because the select is done on the table without any criteria, there is a high probability that the list will be big or will become big.

Comment: can I remove where mdl2.ps_stud_id is null  If I want to check only deference ?

Comment: @RnD: No. [See this a good explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)